# Class instantiated after definition lifetime

Tags: c++, singleton

I've come across some code looking like the following -

```
class A
{
     public:
          A();
          ~A();
}a;
```

This occurs in in `foo.cpp`, and there is a `foo.hpp` where class A sees no use at all. This is the only usage of this class in an entire code base. The instance `a` sees no use anywhere inside `foo.cpp`.

When is `a` created and destroyed?

Since it's been marked as a duplicate I'll highlight/extend the bit that makes it not a duplicate -

Does this style of instantiating a class alongside its definition have a name?

There is a comment alongside this class that describes it as a singleton. Is that correct? I realize it doesn't follow the GoF implementation of a singleton, but this is only instance of A that can exist correct (given that it's not used anywhere else inside of `foo.cpp`)?

Comment: Global variables have a lifetime of the whole programs execution. They should be constructed before the `main` function starts, and be destructed after `main` returns (or `exit` is called).

Comment: And no, it's *not* a singleton in the classic sense. Actually, it should not be possible to create even the `a` object since both the constuctor and destructor are `private`. If what you show is not an actual [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the constructor and destructor is actually `public`, then it's *still* not a singleton, since other objects could then be created (even if none are *currently*).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That was an omission on my part and has been corrected.

Comment: It is important to note that this is equivalent to defining class A and then immediately declaring `A a;`. Therefore, this is only a global variable if this code is in the global scope. Otherwise it is just a locally defined class and `a` is a local variable.